# What does Action<Action> mean?

Tags: c#, generics, recursion, types, system.reactive

I just saw a [brand-new video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Announcing-the-Official-Release-of-Rx) on the Rx framework, and one particular signature caught my eye:

```
Scheduler.schedule(this IScheduler, Action<Action>)
```

At 23:55, Bart de Smet says:

> The earliest version would be *Action of Action*.

If `Action` is a parameterized type, how can it appear unparameterized inside the angle brackets again? Wouldn't it have to be `Action<Action<Action<...>>>` ad infinitum, which is obviously impossible?

Comment: Isn't there a non-generic `Action` type as well? That would explain it :)

Comment: aww, now I feel stupid I didn't make that an answer

Comment: If you really want a type that bakes your noodle, play around with "delegate D D(D d);" for a bit and see what you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Action` has several overloads. One is non-generic, the others take one, two, three, etc. type parameters. Suppose they had different names, the one-argument version being called `Action1`, and the zero-argument (non-generic) being called `Action0`, then the example would be `Action1<Action0>`.

Comment: @pst Please take more care in future when editing other people's answers. You deleted half of my text.

Comment: I did not. If text was deleted it was a concurrency failure on the part of SO (is optimistic concurrency working/employed?). I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: SO is optimistic about the care taken by its users. Apparently too optimistic.

Comment: It's hard to tell if a change has be "lost" because of concurrency issues without an optimistic guard. If you have a problem, please take it to meta.

Answer (score 4):

`Action<T>` describes a delegate that takes a single parameter of type T.  `Action` describes a delegate that takes no parameters.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

- [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx)
- [Action<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

**Action example**

```
Action showMethod = () => { Console.WriteLine("Line"); };

showMethod();
```

**Action<T> example**

```
Action<int> showMethod = (i) => { Console.WriteLine("Line {0}", i); };

showMethod(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Action has a non-generic version with the signature:

```
public delegate void Action();
```

So it is an Action that takes an Action of type void. Looks funny, but is perfectly valid.

Comment: It's an Action that takes a parameter of type Action, not an Action that returns an Action. An example would be: Action doSomething = (someMethod) => someMethod();

Comment: dbowden, actually your example would be an Action<T> rather than the non-generic Action. To make your example into the non-generic version, change it to Action doSomething = () => someMethod();

Comment: @bdowden, you are correct, I got my words mixed up. I edited the post, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Default parameter seems like the easy solution here.

Comment: Default parameter of what...? :(